# How do I make the Netflix OAuth API use my callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, netflix

I have a simple Rails application with which I am trying to use the Netflix API to gain access to some of my subscriber information, such as my history and queue. My problem is that no matter what I do, Netflix will not use my `oauth_callback` url, but instead forwards me to the Netflix site after I authorize the application with my user credentials.

Here is the controller code which is making the request to the Netflix API

```
class ExportController < ApplicationController

  def export
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new( ENV['NETFLIX_KEY'],ENV['NETFLIX_SECRET'],
      :site => "http://api.netflix.com",
      :request_token_url => "http://api.netflix.com/oauth/request_token",
      :access_token_url => "http://api.netflix.com/oauth/access_token", 
      :authorize_url => "https://api-user.netflix.com/oauth/login" )
    request_token = consumer.get_request_token
    session[:request_token]=request_token
    session[:request_token_secret]=request_token.secret
    url = request_token.authorize_url( :oauth_callback => "http://#{ENV['OAUTH_CALLBACK_DOMAIN']}/export_callback/", :oauth_consumer_key => ENV['NETFLIX_KEY'],
      :application_name => ENV['APPLICATION_NAME'] )
    redirect_to url
  end

  def export_callback
    @request_token=OAuth::RequestToken.new(session[:request_token],session[:request_token_secret]) 
    @access_token = @request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
  end
end
```

The controller correctly redirects to `https://api-user.netflix.com/oauth/login` site, with all the parameters correctly set. I get the Netflix Login/Authorize app page.

[image: Netflix Link Account page]

However, if I look at the source of this page, I see in the form that the `oauth_callback` field is set to `oob`

```
      <input type="hidden" name="oauth_callback" value="oob"/>
```

I've checked several different ways, and I am setting the `oauth_callback` parameter just the same as the [Netflix Authentication Walkthrough](http://developer.netflix.com/walkthrough). In fact, when I go through the walkthrough and put in my callback url in their field, it does in fact redirect back to my rails application.

So, my question, does anyone know how to make Netflix respect my `oauth_callback` field?

edit:

```
https://api-user.netflix.com/oauth/login?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fnetflix.dev%2Fexport_callback%2F&oauth_consumer_key=[REMOVED]&oauth_nonce=631831&oauth_timestamp=1321458391&application_name=[REMOVED]&oauth_token=[REMOVED]
```

You can see `oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fnetflix.dev%2Fexport_callback%2F` being set, which is the route to my local rails app.

edit2:

I am using the `oauth (0.4.5)` and `rails (3.1.0)` and `ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]` on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Can you please also provide the request parameters when the request is going to api-user (and don't forget to randomize the hashes!)?

Comment: isn't that the oauth_callback for you consumer.get_request_token call? see http://developer.netflix.com/docs/Security

Comment: @phil pirozhkov I've added the request to api-user.

Comment: @esskar perhaps? not sure how that is supposed to help me. If you go to that page and find the section titled "Ask the Subscriber to Sign In", you will see the step where I am stuck. I make the request to the netflix API via the oauth gem with my callback_url as a parameter, but netflix ignores it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oob` that is in the form probably refers to "out of bounds". The problem is with:

```
request_token = consumer.get_request_token
```

Netflix makes you pass in the callback url when you get the request token, and verifies the url in the login page. In your case, if you change it to:

```
request_token = consumer.get_request_token( 
          :oauth_callback => 
             "http://#{ENV['OAUTH_CALLBACK_DOMAIN']}/export_callback/" )
```

Everything should work from that point on, and the form will get this value. I tested out your code, and got the same `oob` and then added the change, and it gave the correct value in the form.

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Netflix Authentication Walk-Through](http://developer.netflix.com/walkthrough) and see if it works for your account? it did work for me using firefox. (i also copy&pasted the url into IE then and got redirected correcly). You then should try to compare the url from the walk-through with the url you are generating and nail the problem down.

Comment: If you read my question, I already indicated that I used the walk-through to compare my results.

Comment: My bad, it confuses me since the callback is just a normal parameter: not signed or anything; changeling it afterwards is not a problem (I mean after you see the the net fix login screen)!